# jQuery datepicker in Angular FormControl

Tags: jquery, angular, datepicker

I have a problem with binding value with **DateTimePicker jQuery** from **xdsoft**:
https://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I built **FormControl** using **ReactiveFormsModule**

I have `<form [formGroup]="myForm">`

And there are two inputs in it:

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" formControlName="date" />
```

**FormControl** for **"name"** works fine.

However, **FormControl** for **"date"** doesn't show any values in:

```
{{ myform.value | json }}
```

**StackBlitz:**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmsjj7?file=src/app/app.component.ts

GIF showing the problem:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      timepicker: false,
      format: 'd.m.Y',
      onClose: (dateText, inst) => {
      this.myForm.controls['date'].setValue(dateText);
    }
    });
```

## Update

Just remove form control from the date as we are assigning explicitly value to his control.

```
<input type="text" formControlName="name">
<input type="text" id="datetimepicker" />
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ahf35y?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: It's works OK but when I click outside input, my date change to default "Wed Jun 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0200". How to fix it?

Comment: This is default behaviour of Datetimepicker

Comment: Thank you for your help! But unfortunatelly it is useless, because when I choose "10 June" myForm change to "10 June", and when I click outside input, myForm change to "20 June" (today). I want to stay "10 June"

Comment: Np, anyways don't say "it's useless" I pointed the path to set date and method of date time picker.

Comment: @NaturoPower check my updated working example, now when you click outside it will not change date

Comment: Thank you! You are amazing! <3